# how to make a query for getting all w:r/w:t inside the //w:body/w:p using xslt 2.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

This is my Xml File...

```
<w:document>

        <w:body>

           <w:p>
                <w:r>
                    <w:t>
                      Paragraph1
                     </w:t>
                 </w:r>
             </w:p>
          </w:body>
</w:document>
```

**This is my Second XML file...**

```
 <w:document>
    <w:body>
        <w:p>
            <w:r>
               <w:pict>
                    <v:shape>
                       <v:textbox>
                           <w:txbxContent>
                              <w:p>
                                 <w:r>
                                    <w:t>
                                       Paragraph2
                                     </w:t>
                                 </w:r>
                                </w:p>
                             </w:txbxContent>
                           <v:textbox>
                        </v:shape>
                     </w:pict>
                  </w:r>
                </w:p>
              </w:body>
             </w:document>
```

Here, i have written one xslt file and calling my template whenever i found //w:body/w:p/w:r/w:t.

```
   for example,


 <xsl:apply-templates select="//w:body/w:p[w:r[w:t]]">
   </xsl:apply-templates>
```

my own template is

```
<xsl:template match="w:p">
            Do something here
       </xsl:template>
```

my xslt working correctly with my first xml document.But it is not working with second one and also some scenario like that.So, how can i achieve both of this scenario by modifying this query here...

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="?????"> <!-- how to find the case that also matching my second xml file -->
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

Please guide me get out of this issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//w:p[w:r/w:t]">
```

You may aso change the template's match attribute to be slightly more specific:

```
<xsl:template match="w:p[w:r/w:t]"> 
  <!-- Processing here -->
</xsl:template>
```

**Complete code**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:w="w:w">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="//w:p[w:r/w:t]"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="w:p[w:r/w:t]">
  <xsl:value-of select="w:r/w:t"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the first provided XML document** (namespace defined to make it well-formed):

```
<w:document xmlns:w="w:w">
    <w:body>
        <w:p>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>
                 Paragraph1
             </w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
    </w:body>
</w:document>
```

**the correct result is produced**:

```
             Paragraph1
```

**when the same transformation is applied on the second provided "XML"** (it is severely malformed and I spent many minutes until I made it well-formed!!!):

```
<w:document xmlns:w="w:w">
    <w:body>
        <w:p>
            <w:r>
                <w:pict>
                    <v:shape xmlns:v="v:v">
                        <v:textbox>
                            <w:txbxContent>
                                <w:p>
                                    <w:r>
                                        <w:t>
                      Paragraph2
                                        </w:t>
                                    </w:r>
                                </w:p>
                            </w:txbxContent>
                        </v:textbox>
                    </v:shape>
                </w:pict>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
    </w:body>
</w:document>
```

**again the wanted result is produced**:

```
                  Paragraph2
```

Comment: :Sorry Dimitre, It is not working with my above case...i think it is not calling my template...

Comment: @Saravan: If there is *any* element matching the match pattern, then the template has to be selected for execution -- if not, it is possible that you have another template that also matches this element and has higher precedence/priority.

Comment: @Now i have tested only with my second xml file and i found there is no element matching...

Comment: @Saravan: I edited my answer and provided *complete* code which executes correctly on both XML documents -- you can just copy and paste it and run the transformation to verify that it performs as required in both cases. If you can't adjust this to your concrete case, this means that you didn't provide correct information and/or have another problem.

Comment: @Dimitre_::Thank you very much for spent your valuable time for me.Please Let me chk it..